# liblinear's train.exe: "Wrong input format at line 1"

Tags: regression

I'm trying to run liblinear's train.exe on Windows:

```
>train ex1_train.txt
Wrong input format at line 1
```

Here's the beginning of the file. What's wrong?

```
17.592 1:6.1101
9.1302 1:5.5277
13.662 1:8.5186
11.854 1:7.0032
6.8233 1:5.8598
11.886 1:8.3829
4.3483 1:7.4764
12 1:8.5781
6.5987 1:6.4862
3.8166 1:5.0546
3.2522 1:5.7107
15.505 1:14.164
3.1551 1:5.734
7.2258 1:8.4084
0.71618 1:5.6407
3.5129 1:5.3794
5.3048 1:6.3654
0.56077 1:5.1301
3.6518 1:6.4296
5.3893 1:7.0708
```

Answer (score 1):

Liblinear requires the same input format as LibSVM. And, from their README file,

> The format of training and testing data file is:
>
> `<label> <index1>:<value1> <index2>:<value2> ...`
>
> Each line contains an instance and is ended by a '\n' character.  For
>   classification, `<label>` is an integer indicating the class label
>   (multi-class is supported). For regression, `<label>` is the target
>   value which can be any real number. For one-class SVM, it's not used
>   so can be any number.  The pair `<index>:<value>` gives a feature
>   (attribute) value: `<index>` is an integer starting from 1 and `<value>`
>   is a real number. The only exception is the precomputed kernel, where
>   `<index>` starts from 0; see the section of precomputed kernels. Indices
>   must be in ASCENDING order.

Since we don't have the entire file, the best answer we can provide is that make sure all these instructions are followed. E.g., there is no TAB instead of space, there is no '\r\n' instead of '\n', etc. A good way to debug would be to take a few lines and keep adding until you get the error.

```
head -10 <yourfile> > tmp10
head -20 <yourfile> > tmp20
```

etc. And see where the error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

My problems were that: you can't use zero as a feature id, and your features need to be sorted.